# PCRE character class subtraction

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a flow of data with some entries.

- Entries contain 1 mandatory field and 1 optional field.
- Fields are separated from each other by semicolon `;`.
- Fields contain any printable symbols **EXCEPT SEMICOLON** `;`
- Mandatory field should be 1-60 symbols in length.
- Optional field could be 0-60 symbols in length.

I would like to match all fields within entries.
I use negative lookahead assertion to subtract semicolon from `[:print:]` POSIX character class but it seems don't work with length-limited fields.

My data:

```
[1427894078] SERV;ICE ALERT: example.com ;Current Load;CRITICAL;SOFT;3;CRITICAL - load average: 1.96, 1.29, 0.59
```

My regex (PCRE):

```
((?!;)[[:print:]]{1,60});((?!;)[[:print:]]{0,60})
```

What I expect to get:

```
Match 1:
Group 1: [1427894078] SERV
Group 2: ICE ALERT: example.com 

Match 2:
Group 1: Current Load
Group 2: CRITICAL

Match 3:
Group 1: SOFT
Group 2: 3
```

What I wrongly get:

```
Match 1:
Group 1: [1427894078] SERV;ICE ALERT: example.com ;Current Load
Group 2: CRITICAL;SOFT;3;CRITICAL - load average: 1.96, 1.29, 0.59
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/3uObB5/2

Comment: `CRITICAL - load average: 1.96, 1.29, 0.59` shouldn't be matched at all?

Comment: I have prepared the following regex: `([^;\n]{1,60});([^;\n]{0,60})` that does exactly matches your groups but I am not sure about the logic behind the optional field...
https://regex101.com/r/H0OQ5O/1/

Comment: Optional field could be zero-length but enclosed by fields delimiters. Meaning `FIELD1;;` is an entry with `FIELD1` mandatory field and empty optional field. Note that delimiters are still in place. `CRITICAL - load average: 1.96, 1.29, 0.59` is excluded from matching because it doesn't followed by a delimiter and second field. `[^;\n]` includes non-printable symbols which is prohibited by fields format. Also `[:print:]` character class INCLUDES whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are totally close. The only problem with your regex is that you didn't include lookahead into the quantified cluster:

- `(?!;)[[:print:]]{1,60}` should be `(?:(?!;)[[:print:]]){1,60}`

Now it matches right chunks of characters (see live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/wSfays/1)):

```
((?:(?!;)[[:print:]]){1,60});((?:(?!;)[[:print:]]){0,60})
```

However, there is a better alternative (see live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/idff73/1)):

```
([^\p{C};]{1,60});([^\p{C};]{0,60})
```

Comment: `([^\p{C};]{1,60});([^\p{C};]{0,60})` better than my `([^;\n]{1,60});([^;\n]{0,60})`